# Create an api to expose the dl model created using fast.ai CNN

Tags: python, flask, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I am doing image classification using fast.ai. I have created the dl model. Now I want to expose the model as an api. I am using the following repository https://github.com/alexcnwy/flask_fastai_CNN
to expose the dl model. It needs the model weights.

I use the fastai/courses/dl1/lesson1.ipynb and I save the weights like this:

```
arch=resnet34
data = ImageClassifierData.from_paths(PATH, tfms=tfms_from_model(arch, sz))
learn = ConvLearner.pretrained(arch, data, precompute=True)
learn.save('modelweights')
```

but after saving the model weights (modelweights.h5) into flask_fastai_CNN/static/_model when I run `python server.py`,
It throws the following error

```
### start server  2018-07-19 12:01:39.808413

### image upload folder: /home/ubuntu/flask_fastai_CNN/static/_uploads/unknown/

### data folder: /home/ubuntu/flask_fastai_CNN/static/data/redux
Using gpu device 0: Tesla K80 (CNMeM is disabled, cuDNN Mixed dnn version. The header is from one version, but we link with a different version (5103, 7005))
Using Theano backend.

### initializing model: 
VVV/home/ubuntu/flask_fastai_CNN/static/_model/modelweights.h5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 52, in <module>
    vgg = Vgg16()
  File "/home/ubuntu/flask_fastai_CNN/utils/vgg16.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.create()
  File "/home/ubuntu/flask_fastai_CNN/utils/vgg16.py", line 84, in create
    model.load_weights(trained_model_path)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2494, in load_weights
    f = h5py.File(filepath, mode='r')
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 269, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 99, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 78, in h5py.h5f.open
IOError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

I have deployed the fast.ai in AWS ubuntu p2.xlarge instance. I have also used the h5debug and h5dump command to access the file, but both results in `cannot open file`. Please anyone could tell me where I am wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get this to work ? I'm doing something similar (trying to serve a FastAI model, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: What's the output of `find /home/ubuntu/flask_fastai_CNN/static/_model`?

Comment: modelweights.h5

Comment: @AndreasKlintberg yes it works now. I was not saving the model weights correctly.